# issue on dropdown li menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript and the following HTML excerpt code. I have an element with the `fantasyLink` id, and I want that when it is clicked, the `li` dropdown shows but it doesn't do anything, but when I run the code on console, it does the action. The clicked element is circled in the image.

[image]

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fantasyLink').on('click', function (){
                $('body').find('#dropLogin').click();
    });
});
```

```html
<li class="dropdown" id="linkLogin">
                                <a id="dropLogin" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div id="message"></div>
                                                <label class="label-login">Iniciar sesión con:</label>
                                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                                    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" data-size="xlarge" onlogin="checkLoginState();" class="btn">
                                                        Facebook
                                                    </fb:login-button>
                                                </div>
```

**NOTE: I have also tried using trigger, adding the `open` class to the `linkLogin` element so it shows, toggle the class, none of them working...**

Comment: if you do console.log inside your function do you get the output ? maybe try event.preventDefault(); to stop the default behavior.

Comment: Yes, I get the output, still doesn't work preventing the default behavior, and the "login" text, gets color changed as if the mouse was over it.

Comment: Try  $('body').find('#dropLogin').trigger( "click" );

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi Done, it does the same thing :/

Comment: Hmm, sorry man I am out of options. By the way you can just do $('#dropLogin') instead of $('bod').find

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi Yeah, but I'm trying the less possible thing that could have worked, so I left it like that, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Got it. By the way do you get any output when you do console.log($('#dropLogin')) inside your function  ?

Comment: I get all the selector properties when console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it to work:

```
$('#fantasyLink').on('click', function (e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('#dropLogin').trigger( "click" ); 
}
```

That `stopPropagation` seems to make the trick but if someone could explain the reason it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do `$('body').find('#dropLogin').click()`

Because of the `.find()` returns an array of objects the way that would work is if you did: `$('body').find('#dropLogin')[0].click()`

However, you shouldn't need to do that. Simply -

```
$('#dropLogin').click();
```

That should do that trick for you. That is the beauty of `jQuery` and selectors if you have an `ID` you shouldn't need to search the DOM for it, just use the selector.

**Alternatively** instead of using a `click` event that, from what it seems like only gets clicked programmatically you can just create a simple function -

```
$(document).on('click', '#fantasyLink', function() {
    dropLogin();
});

var dropLogin = function() {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: You are right, but using `$('#fantasyLink').click(); ` didn't work, using `e.stopPropagation();` before launching the click event did the work for me.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez So I think that has something to do with the multiple click events. `ie` one click event programmatically clicks another click event. I would recommend trying to use the alternative. You should also post your `click()` function for the `dropLogin` But from what it seems like it is pointless for you to create a click event function only to be called by a different click function.

Comment: Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 1):

`$('#fantasyLink').on('clic', function ()` seems to be wrong. should be `click`.

Comment: That was my mistake, but still, not working with `clic`.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez no, I think Ulf made a mistake. he meant to say that you have to write $('#fantasyLink').on('click', function ()). It is always spelled "click"

Comment: @NicolaPedretti I always get confused with that word, but still, not working  with that correction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave a comment, but I need a few more rep points!

Just to confirm, is the initial onclick firing? If not sometimes I find this works better even though they both should work:

`$(document).on('click', '#fantasyLink', function (){ ..`